# Firebase facebook login not working on heroku

Tags: javascript, facebook, firebase, heroku, firebase-authentication

I am trying to login using facebookAuthProvider of firebase, it is working on **localhost** but not on heruko server.

No outputs or error are being displayed in logs. It just open popup of facebook and after accepting it just get closed nothing else. No output no user registered. Nothing!

Here is the code:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then(function(result) {
     var token = result.credential.accessToken;
     var user = result.user;
     const currentDate = new Date().toLocaleString();
     console.log(token);
     console.log(user);
     console.log(user.displayName);
}).catch(function(error) {
     console.log(error.code);
    console.log(error.message);
});
```

Comment: what about the app settings? are they correct on facebook? with the heroku url instead of localhost?

Comment: why not use console.log(result) and console.log(error) instead of trying to access specific sub-variables?

Comment: In firebase we just have to provide firebase handler url in facebook app settings. And that is `https://civixxvice-xxe5.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler` And it's correct

Comment: why use heroku anyway? firebase offers hosting too.

Comment: Make sure you whitelist your application production domain in the Firebase Console.

Comment: Yes, It did the trick. Thanks. Please add an answer so i can accept it.